# Add custom build/prepare step to project

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, ionic3

I have an ionic app targeting Android and iOS.

What i want to achieve, but i'm unsure about how to do, is being able to specify a command line flag when building/preparing the code for both platforms.
My first goal would be to replace a resource with another one - in this case an image - used only for test versions (Like replacing the release icon with the beta icon).

How to do this?
And is it even possible using `ionic build/prepare`?

Comment: Maybe you can use **[Ionic's hooks](https://ionicframework.com/docs/cli/configuration#hooks)** - specially `ionic:build:before`. I've done something with hooks for example to copy the app version from the `config.xml` file to a service... so maybe you can build something to replace the resources with it :/

Comment: @sebaferreras Care to create an answer post with your info?... So i can give you the credit you deserve.

Comment: Glad to hear that my comment helped you somehow! But to be honest the info I gave you is maybe enough for a comment, but definitely not enough for an answer... It'd be great if you can create an answer explaining how you solved your question and that way **I** can give you the credits **you** deserve :)

Comment: @sebaferreras Here you go... Let me know if i can improve it in the answer's comments.

Comment: It looks great!! Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using [Ionic Hooks](https://ionicframework.com/docs/cli/configuration#hooks) (kudos @sebaferreras) i managed to get it working as follows:

1. Add the hooks to `ionic.config.json`:

   `"hooks": {
      "build:before": "./scripts/build-before.js",
      "serve:before": "./scripts/serve-before.js"
    }`
2. Create the hook scripts & resources to use. (E.g. a simple hook script for `ionic build` - without checks, for simplicity:

```
module.exports = function(ctx)
{
  // Use console.log(ctx); to print the context to the console when running 'ionic build/serve'

  const projectDir = ctx.project.dir;

  if(isDevBuild(ctx))
  {
    useDevelopmentImage(projectDir);
    console.log('Using development logo.');
  }
  else
  {
    useProductionImage(projectDir);
    console.log('Using production logo.');
  }
};

function isDevBuild(context)
{
  if(context.build.prod)
    return false;

  return true;
}

function useDevelopmentImage(projectDir)
{
  const devLogoPath = projectDir + '/images/dev_logo.png';
  // Could also use context.project.src instead of projectDir + '/src...'
  const targetPath  = projectDir + '/src/assets/imgs/logo.png';

  let fs = require('fs');
  fs.copyFileSync(devLogoPath, targetPath); 
}

function useProductionImage(projectDir)
{
  const prodLogoPath = projectDir + '/images/prod_logo.png';
  const targetPath   = projectDir + '/src/assets/imgs/logo.png';

  let fs = require('fs');
  fs.copyFileSync(prodLogoPath, targetPath);
}
```